# XMLHttpRequest at xxx from origin xxx has been blocked by CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: spring-boot, cors

hi I am working on spring boot, angular 8, and mongodb. I am facing the error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

when i test same code on postman it work perfectly fine, however it don't work angular, and because chrome using the CORS policy.

My code:

```
package com.sani.springbootrestfulapi;
public class SpringBootMongoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMongoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "PATCH")
                    .allowedHeaders("Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

below: employee controller code

```
package com.sani.springbootrestfulapi.controller;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("employee")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;
    @Autowired
    private OrganizationService organizationService;
    @PostMapping("/save") 
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity> save(@RequestBody EmployeeEntity emp) {
        if (empService.findByrNumber(emp.getrNumber())) 
            return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity>(HttpStatus.FOUND);
        else {
            organizationService.joinOrganization(emp);
            return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
    @PutMapping("/update") /* here we need to pass id, the spring will consider as update */
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity> update(@RequestBody EmployeeEntity emp) {
        EmployeeEntity employee = empService.getOne(emp.getId());
        if (employee != null) {
            organizationService.joinOrganization(emp);
            return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else
            return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    @GetMapping("/activeemployeesummary")
    public List<EmployeeEntity> getActiveEmployeeSummary() {
        List<EmployeeEntity> employee = new ArrayList<>();
        empService.getActiveEmployeeSummary().forEach(employee::add);
        return employee;
    }
    @GetMapping("/inactiveemployeesummary")
    public List<EmployeeEntity> getInactiveEmplo`enter code here`yeeSummary() {
        List<EmployeeEntity> employee = new ArrayList<>();
        empService.getInactiveEmployeeSummary().forEach(employee:`enter code here`:add);
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will CORS issue only in browser due to Same origin policy restriction in browser.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

can you please give a sample code where exactly i have to write the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200110/unable-to-enable-cors-in-spring-boot-websecurityconfigureradapter/59201452#59201452

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. please find below error which got, and header: ---GENERAL---
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

---RESPONSE HEADER---
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2020 07:05:28 GMT

Comment: --REQUEST HEADER--
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/employee-master
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36

Comment: error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:5847 ERROR Error Code: 0
Message: Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary: 0 Unknown Error

Comment: i have added the below code as per in your last comments :@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMongoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMongoApplication.class, args);
 }

Comment: @Bean 
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {     
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration(); 
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true); 
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("localhost:4200"); 
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*"); 
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*"); 
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(); 
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);     
    return source; 
   }
}

Comment: Make sure you have added `*` in this two method calls. `configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");`
`configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");`

Comment: hi, in my  SpringBootMongoApplication class i already given * in allowed methods, and header. but still i am getting the error. please find below angular code call method: public getActiveEmployeeSummary(): Observable<employeeMasterBean[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200'});
    return this.http.get<employeeMasterBean[]>("http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary", { observe: 'response', headers: headers})
    .pipe(
      map(response => response.body)
    );
  }

Comment: what error you are getting in the browser console.

Comment: error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: hi, any updates. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this `@Bean` in your `@Configuration` or your main class.

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(
            Arrays.asList("GET","POST","HEAD","DELETE","PUT","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setMaxAge(1l);
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, I will revert once I try it out.

Comment: Dear, I am still getting the same error: if you want I can upload my projects files and if you can check it out. thanks.              Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/employee/activeemployeesummary' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Can u update complete console screenshot and update it in your question.

Comment: i had updated the console error screenshot. find link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236921/i-have-updated-the-console-error-screen-shot

Comment: hi, I did remove all security configuration, and tested my project even then it gives the same error, and the screenshot is given in above comments. so in my new project there is not security reconfiguration.

Comment: Did you added `@Bean` method ?? I mean the answer?

Comment: yes i added @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()  in application module.

Comment: yes i added the @Bean in main class. yes the api GET, POST, PUT working in postman.

Comment: mark your Main class with `@Configuration` annotation.

Comment: I marked my main class with @Configuration annotation, but no success. still the same error.

Comment: can you send your email address so i can transfer you the project files. as the github has file limit.

Comment: spring boot api + angular project = 500mb file size.

Comment: Instead of updating as rar file can you post the complete backend code in github.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just missed that header =>

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```